# Working with X Path Queries

Tags: xpath

[image]

For the 15 element with the function `preceding::em` what are the elements that match and also for the 7th element with code `//fig` what are the elements that match and why because I'm not sure?

Comment: This should most probably be tagged as *homework*.

Comment: Also, this question will be useless to future readers as soon as the link dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, both of your expressions will yield no results.

`preceding::em` on element 15 will look at all of the nodes that are children of 14 and occur before element 15.  No such element occurs before 15.

`//fig` on element 7 will look at all descendants of element 7 and get the ones that are fig elements.  element 7 has no descendants, thus this results in an empty node set as well.